# Spring Security @Secured annotation and Scala controller

Tags: java, spring, scala, spring-security, annotations

In a mixed Java/Scala Spring (v3.2) project I want to create a scala-based controller, and secure it with @Secure annotation. For java controllers this works just fine, but when I add @Secure annotation to the scala controller it disappears from URL mapping on application startup.

Sample code:

```
@Controller
@Secured(Array("ROLE_USER"))
class TestController {
  @RequestMapping(value = Array("/show"), method = Array(RequestMethod.GET))
  def show = {
    "helloTemplate"
  }
}
```

The same if I put secure annotation per method - the whole controller class will disappear from URL mapping (even if there are unsecured methods). No exceptions or warnings in the log. If I secure this URL via spring-security intercept-url in xml configuration - all things works fine (without @Secure annotation on controller). Spring and spring-security configuration via xml files and annotation-driven configuration is turned on. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring 4/Spring you must enable `proxyTargetClass = true` to use CGLIB class proxying. This is superior to java class Proxying when working with scala.

SpringBoot

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
```